# How can I get specific rows from an excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to read in an Excel file that has the following structure:

```
            A                 B         C       D        E
  ╔════════════════════╦════════════╦═══════╦═══════╦══════════╗
1 ║ Project Name       ║            ║       ║       ║          ║
  ╠════════════════════╬════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬══════════╣
2 ║ Date of generation ║            ║       ║       ║          ║
  ╠════════════════════╬════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬══════════╣
3 ║ ID                 ║ Type       ║ Value ║ Color ║ Capacity ║
  ╠════════════════════╬════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬══════════╣
4 ║ 1                  ║ Car        ║ 1,000 ║ Red   ║ 2        ║
  ╠════════════════════╬════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬══════════╣
5 ║ 2                  ║ Truck      ║ 800   ║ Green ║ 12       ║
  ╠════════════════════╬════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬══════════╣
6 ║ 3                  ║ Helicopter ║ 5,000 ║ White ║ 4        ║
  ╚════════════════════╩════════════╩═══════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

As you can see, the data headings are on row 3, and the information continues underneath. If I read the frame in like so:

```
df = pandas.read_excel("sample.xls", sheetname=0, skiprows=2, header=0)
```

my dataframe has the correct portion of data, but I'm unable to read the information in the first cells, A1 and A2.

I've tried the following as well, to 'slice' a new dataframe once I have the top two values taken. I get an error:

```
df = pandas.read_excel("sample.xls", sheetname=0, skiprows=0, header=None)

project_name = df.iloc[0][0]
project_date = df.iloc[1][0]

new_header = df.iloc[2]         #grab the first row for the header
df = df[3:]                     #take the data less the header row
df.rename(columns = new_header) #set the header row as the df header

#tidyup   
df = df.fillna('')              #convert NaN (blank) cells to empty string
df.applymap(str)                #convert all columns to str
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()   #strip whitespace before and after headers
df_obj = df.select_dtypes(['object']) #select all object columns (not int/float columns)
df[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()) #strip (trim whitepace) of all object columns
```

Running the above I get an error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')
```

Its not clear to me why as the same 'tidyups section but reading the df as in my first code line above work.

Is there a way I can get to the 'above header' information without creating a whole new dataframe by reading the file twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is problem you forget to assign back:

```
df = df.applymap(str)
```

Also better (faster) is instead `applymap` use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df = df.astype(str)
```

All together:

```
project_name = df.iloc[0, 0]
project_date = df.iloc[1, 0]

new_header = df.iloc[2]        
df = df[3:]      
df.columns = new_header.str.strip()
df.columns.name = None

df = df.astype(str).reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
print (df)
  ID        Type  Value  Color Capacity
0  1         Car  1,000    Red        2
1  2       Truck    800  Green       12
2  3  Helicopter  5,000  White        4
```